# how to hide the push notification bar in phonegap android

Tags: java, android, cordova

I want to show the application window in full screen where it looks like a game screen...
Please help me..

```
package play.lear.com;



import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;



import android.os.Bundle;


import android.view.WindowManager;

public class PlayActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a flag you can set in config.xml for full screen

```
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

Comment: Work with this corrections

public class PlayActivity extends DroidGap {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN | 
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);

Answer (score 1):

[Phonegap's Notification](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#Notification) has nothing to do with push notification.

Check [this](http://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android-gcm-push-notifications-guide/) for integrating Pushwoosh for Android with Phonegap